# how to implement editing/formating text area in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, textarea

i want to implement text box(text area) as shown in picture .I know the simple textarea but dont know this type of text area which gives formatting ,numbering facility,Since iam new to rails plz help me[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that Rails provides, but there are many javascript wysiwyg plugins that solve this problem. This has worked well for me before: https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails