# Ruby on Rails rich text editor solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, richtextbox

I have a text_area, and I just want the user to insert a URL to some text. Is this possible?

This is what I have

```
<%= f.text_area :item, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "List your items (separated by each line)" %>
```

What I'm trying to do is create a list with text area. So if user starts typing and presses enter, it'll be another line. This is possible because I'm using `simple_format`.

Is it possible to do something where user can add URL to some of their list items?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There is [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gem that previously was auto_link method in Rails 3. It can recognize links in your text.

```
auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello to david@loudthinking.com")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> and
#     say hello to <a href=\"mailto:david@loudthinking.com\">david@loudthinking.com</a>"
```

**Updated after comments**

I thought you were looking for a way to display embedded URLs. If you want  a full scale editor then you can use any of available rich text editors such as [ckeditor-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails).

Some more editors:

1) [tinymce](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails)

2) [quill](https://github.com/the-robear/quill-rails)

3) [mercury](http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/)

So, in general, you have tree options: 1) let users insert links into your text area and use rails_autolink gem; 2) use one of the editors and limit whatever editing options you want to expose; 3) write your own editor that parses only links.

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to do some sort of rich text editor in a text_area field. Something similar to stackoverflow's textbox when asking a question

Comment: I didn't want a full scale editor... I just wanted someone to post a URL to their text. I don't need any other item within the text editor.

Comment: @hellomello: I am afraid that you will still have to use some kind of full scale editor and customize options that you want to show to users. Last time I wanted to limit such things I used tinymice. I think it is the most simple one.

Comment: @hellomello: You are not the first one to ask this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588592/how-to-implement-editing-formating-text-area-in-rails I just gave you more options.